# browser elements positioning differences

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, html-parsing, transformation

I've made a simple round timer by placing 60 div's for active and inactive timer state accordingly using geometry formula:

```
x = x0 + r * Cos(theta * PI / 180);
y = y0 + r * Sin(theta * PI / 180);
```

But browsers seemed to place elements with the wrong space between them and changing formula value manually didn't help it so i decided to accept this kind of behaviour.

Until I checked it in IE, which happened to parse those coordinates differently and, actually, be the only browser to place elements properly, forming a perfectly round circle, therefore extending those elements outside of parent's dimensions.

My first thought was about differences in browsers parser values rounding. That is, IE seems to round values with precision of two digits after the decimal point, while others are much more precise. Not sure how they render those values thought, so I can't be sure about those differences.

I actually need my timer to look like IE draws it. So, I would appreciate your thoughts on this topic.

Elements are placed like this:

```
or(var z = 0; z < items; z++) {
        segment_inactive = $("<div class='segment_inactive'></div>"),
            segment_active = $("<div class='segment_active'></div>");

        var x = 80  + 80 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * z / items);
        var y = 80  + 80 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * z / items);

        d += 6;

        $("#timer").append(segment_inactive, segment_active);

        segment_inactive.css({
            left:x +"px",
            top:+ y +"px",
            transform: "rotate("+d+"deg)",
            display: "block"
        });

        segment_active.css({
            left:x +"px",
            top:+ y +"px",
            transform: "rotate("+d+"deg)",
            display: "none"
        });
    }
```

and the its just show/hide toggle.

You can view this timer on jsfiddle link below. View it in different browsers and IE in particular.

http://jsfiddle.net/69cAa/4/

Comment: Remove `-webkit-transform-origin: top;` from `.segment...` classes, and the circle will "grow" to the same size in Chrome as [it appears](http://jsfiddle.net/mSxLe/) in IE and FF.

Comment: It does grow, but that's not a reason for poor positioning after all. You can tell that the space between elements is still varies for all browsers but IE, which renders it maybe not perfectly, but much better than others.

Answer (score 0):

So i did my little research playing with different values rounding for transformation/positioning, resolutions/zoom level and i've noticed few things:

- zooming page in/out actually adjust timer making it display properly on high zooming factor.

It is true that every browser rounds up values as he pleases. The problem appears to be with browsers dealing with sub-pixel and rounding floating-point number value into an integer one, which is not a problem on high dpi but it lacks pixel capacity on low dpi.

So, i guess it's not the inconsistency of value rounding but the lack of pixel capacity on screen that parser can use to adjust elements properly on page.

- IE deals with zooming pages differently then the others(as he always does everything his own way). Zoom behaviour in IE actually similar to "transform: scale()" in other browsers. That is, it doesn't trigger page reflow.

But the thing is that IE displays timer properly on high resolution as well.

So i assume that ie somehow renders timer with proper sizing/positioning and doesn't reflow it on different resolutions.

- strangely enough, they say that browser parser has to round number in order to adjust his size/position, but changing element position from 1px to 2 px appears differently on values 1.0 1.3 1.6 1.7 1.9 and 2.0

It's not a constant values that have to be reached in order to visually move element but there's always more than two breaking point.

Still looking for the answer. Would really appreciate your thoughts on subject.